# Getting back a aws instance after shutdown now?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new with AWS, and in order to save money I shutdown my machine using `sudo shutdown now`. Now I don't know how to restart the machine? Is there any way I can get it back? I can reboot from the aws console that will reset the public dns/ip, and I will have to reset all of my hostfiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting your instance after stop(shutdown) which is different from reboot. Use Elastic IP which will not change between starts.

From the dashboard, on the left pane, select `Elastic IPs`
[image]

Allocate an elastic IP if you do not have one available. Then select the instance and choose Associate Address from Action dropdown.

[image]

After this, the IP remain will same even after stop/start. Read more about [Elastic IP Addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Reboot the instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-reboot.html) using the AWS console.

Rebooting does not affect the instance's public ip or dns. Please see the docs for this and more information.

Comment: Everytime I reboot my instance, it resets the public dns and ip. I've verified it.
 is there any setting I can use to prevent that?